OLE DB or ODBC error: Evaluation resulted in a stack overflow and cannot continue
One of my queries, in powerbi destop, contains Table.Combine right after let and i am trying to use is Table.Buffer but still the error persists. how to get around with this ? many thnaks in advance.
let
    Append = Table.Buffer ( Table.Combine({Query1, Query2}) ) 
    more_steps = ...
    in
more_steps


Does it work if Query1 and Query2 are smaller tables (do a top 500 on each of them). If so, the tables are too large for the memory you have available.
